# Executing a program that has codes that import from another module

Tags: python, import, directory

I have searched multiple questions regarding this problem and although there are good answers, I haven't been able to find the exact solution to what I have.

I have a folder structure like this.

```
  root 
    ├── subprogram 
    │       └── module_1
    │       │      └──__init__.py
    │       │      └──dependency_0.py
    │       └── module_2
    │              └──__init__.py
    │              └──dependency_1.py
    │
    └── main.py
```

From main.py, I do something like,

> from subprogram.module_1.dependency_0 import ExampleClass

While inside the subprogram.moudle_1.dependency_0.py it does something like,

> from module_2 import dependency_1

**What is the least invasive** (I make minimal to no change to ANYTHING inside the subprogram) method of using that ExampleClass from the root program?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you should need to make any changes. Imports in a module are not affected by where the program that imports it is located.

Comment: is what you've tried not working? and if not, what is happening instead?

Comment: @Vin So what happens is that an error occurs in 

from module_2 import dependency_1

I get module not found error.

Comment: Can you try (1) placing an empty `__init__.py` inside `subprogram`, and (2) `from subprogram.module_2 import dependency_1` from inside `module_1.py`.

Comment: @Vin That should solve the problem, but if I do that, I would be touching the module_1.py file. I need the least invasive method since my capability to change module_1.py is bound due to the fact that it is a persistent class - used in a pickled file which is opened from ExampleClass.